# How can I know which the subclass of sealed class will return when I use Compose in Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The `Result<out R>` is a sealed class which hold three subclass `Success`, `Error` and `Loading`.

The fun `Greeting` is `@Composable`.

By my design, I define `queryList` as `Result` class, and it is assigned as `Loading` first, then it will be `Success` or `Error`.

1:  But the following code can't be compiled as the following error information, what's wrong with my Code?

2:  Is there a better solution for my design?

**Compile error**

*Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.*

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(
    name: String,
    mViewMode:SoundViewModel= viewModel()
) {
    Column() {
       //The following code cause error.  
       val queryList by produceState(initialValue = Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>>.Loading ) {
          value = mViewMode.listRecord()
       }

       when (queryList){
          is Loading -> { ...}
          is Error  -> { ...}
          is Success -> {...}
       }

    }
}       

class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel()
{
    fun listRecord(): Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>>{
        return  aSoundMeter.listRecord()
    }

}
    
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
    object Loading : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `queryList` is backed by a delegate, it can not be final. 
This means in theory, each time you access it, it might hold a different value. The kotlin compiler is very pessimistic about this and assumes that between the time the `is Result.Success` branch of your `when` statement is selected and `val mydata = queryList.data` is executed, the value of `queryList` might have changed.

To solve this, you can assign the current value of `queryList` to a final variable and work with that one instead:

```
when (val currentList = queryList) {
    is Result.Error -> {}
    is Result.Loading -> {}
    is Result.Success -> {
        SomeComposable(currentList.data) //currentList is properly smart-cast to Result.Success
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But `val queryList by produceState(initialValue = Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>>.Loading )` can't be compiled

Comment: you are probably missing the imports for the delegate methods of `State`, so try adding
`import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue` and `import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue`.

Comment: Thanks! but I get the same error after I add `import androidx.compose.runtime.*`

Comment: At present, I have to use the code   `val aResult: Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>> = Result.Loading      val queryList by produceState(initialValue = aResult) { value = mViewMode.listRecord()   }`

Comment: Is there the more better solution?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. `Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>>.Loading` is not valid kotlin code, because `Result.Loading` already declared its parameter type as `Nothing`. Explicitely declaring the type of `produceState` should solve your issue:
`val queryList by produceState<Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>>>(initialValue = Result.Loading ) {
    value = mViewMode.listRecord()
}`

Comment: I would also like to mention that using flow as a return value of a state is probably not a good idea, if you are dealing with Flows the viewmodel should probably flatten them to a single `StateFlow<Result<<List<MRecord>>>`

Comment: Thank you,  your way is great.  But if I use `StateFlow<Result<<List<MRecord>>>`, I should assign `Result.Loading` before I query database.  How can I emit `Result.Loading` first before I query data and return the data of `Result.Success`?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663562/how-can-i-emit-result-loading-first-before-i-query-data-and-return-the-data-of-r