# How can I emit Result.Loading first before I query data and return the data of Result.Success in Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin

I use the following Code A to query records ,the data are wrapped with sealed class `Result<out R>`.

The `val queryList` is assigned with `Result.Loading` first, then it is assigned with `Result.Success` and wrapped data, the different UI will be loaded based the different value of `queryList`.

I think the `queryList` is only assigned with `Result.Loading` onetime, the `queryList` will keep return `Result.Success` when I launch  `mViewMode.listRecord()` again and again, right?

So I hope the `queryList` is always assigned with `Result.Loading` before I  launch `mViewMode.listRecord()` and return `Result.Success` , how can I fix the code?

Maybe do I need to modify Code B? or do I need to redesign data structure? or is there the better solution?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column( ) {       

        val aResult: Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>> = Result.Loading

        val queryList by produceState(initialValue = aResult) {
            value = mViewMode.listRecord()
        }

        when (queryList){
            is Result.Error  ->  { ...}
            is Result.Loading -> { ... }
            is Result.Success -> { ... }
        }

    }
}


class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(...): ViewModel()
{
    fun listRecord(): Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>>{
        return  aRecordRepository.listRecord()
    }   

}


class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val mRecordDao:RecordDao){
    fun listRecord(): Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>> {
        val temp = mRecordDao.listRecord()
        return Result.Success(temp)
    }

}


interface  RecordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM record_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
    fun listRecord():  Flow<List<MRecord>>
}


sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
    object Loading : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

**Code B**

```
...
class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val mRecordDao:RecordDao){
    fun listRecord(): Result<Flow<List<MRecord>>> {
        val temp = mRecordDao.listRecord()
        return Result.Success(temp) //How can I return Result.Loading first, then return Result.Success(temp)?
    }

}

...
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `Flow<List<MRecord>>` from `RecordDao.listRecord()`? Flow is used when you want to observe the data, meaning Room re runs the query automatically if it detects data changes in the database and sends it to the flow. From your code snippet, it looks like you want to call `listRecord` only once. In that case you should change it to `suspend fun listRecord(): List<MRecord>`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I need Flow<List<MRecord>> from RecordDao.listRecord()

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `StateFlow` in your view model representing `Result` and connect it to your `RecordRepository` as follows and then convert it to compose state using `collectAsState`

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(soundViewModel: SoundViewModel = SoundViewModel()) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        soundViewModel.listRecord()
    }

    Column {
        val queryList: Result by soundViewModel.dataResult.collectAsState()
        when (queryList) {
            is Result.Error -> {
                ...
            }
            is Result.Loading -> {
                ...
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}

class SoundViewModel {
    private val _dataResult: MutableStateFlow<Result> = MutableStateFlow(Result.Loading) // private mutable state flow
    val dataResult = _dataResult.asStateFlow() // publicly exposed as read-only state flow

    private val recordRepository = RecordRepository()

    suspend fun listRecord() {
        recordRepository.listRecord().collect {
            _dataResult.value = Result.Success(it)
        }
    }
}

class RecordRepository  {
    fun listRecord(): Flow<List<Int>> = flow {
        emit(listOf(1))
        delay(1000L)
        emit(listOf(2, 3))
    }
}

sealed interface Result {
    object Loading : Result
    data class Success(val lst: List<Int>) : Result
    data class Error(val err: Throwable) : Result
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think that your way seems the same with my way, right?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing is: When you expose a Flow from Room, it only emits each list after there's a database change **and** a new query is completed. There is no in-between signal from the flow to indicate that the database change is detected but the new query isn't completed yet.

One possible solution is if you create a flow in your repository that when something that happens modifies the database, it restarts with a new emission of Result.Loading and then emits the DAO flow again. This way, your Flow is protected from missing any changes, even if you somehow miss showing a loading state.

You could use a shared flow in the Repository if there's more than one flow you want to handle this way. Use it with `flatMapLatest`, so every time you do something that is likely to cause a database change, the existing upstream `listRecord` flow from the DAO will be cancelled so you can get a new Loading state before collecting it again.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this. It's only an idea.

```
class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val mRecordDao:RecordDao){
    private expectedChangeTicker = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(replay = 1, bufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)

    suspend fun addSomething(someThing: SomeThing) {
        // Call this in every repository function that might cause listRecord to change
        expectedChangeTicker.emit(Unit)
        mRecordDao.addSomething(someThing)
    }

    val listRecord: Flow<Result<List<MRecord>> =
        expectedChangeTicker.flatMapLatest {
            flow {
                emit(Result.Loading)
                emitAll(mRecordDao.listRecord().map { Result.Success(it) })
            }
        }

}
```

I don't know Compose, so I'm not sure how you should expose this Flow in your ViewModel. Notice I changed it from `Result<Flow...>` to `Flow<Result...>`, which I think is more likely what you need. Here is my guess at how it should be done:

```
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(...): ViewModel()
{
    val listRecord: Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> = 
        aRecordRepository.listRecord
            .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), replay = 1)

}

@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column( ) {       

        val aResult: Result<List<MRecord>> = Result.Loading

        val queryList by produceState(initialValue = Result.Loading) {
            value = mViewMode.listRecord
        }

        when (queryList){
            is Result.Error  ->  { ...}
            is Result.Loading -> { ... }
            is Result.Success -> { ... }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems you don't use the function `addSomething()`

Comment: That’s just an example of one of the functions you would have in your repo for interacting with the database. Any function you have that might modify the database should post to the ticker flow to initiate loading state in your other flow.

Comment: Thanks! Why do I need to launch `expectedChangeTicker.emit(Unit)` when I execute `mRecordDao.addSomething(someThing)` ?

Comment: I think `emit(Result.Loading)` is always  launched first when I launch `val listRecord` every time in your code.

Comment: Will  `expectedChangeTicker.emit(Unit)`  effect `val listRecord: Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>` ?

Comment: Thanks! Your code can be compiled correctly, but I can't get the result, it seems that both `emit(Result.Loading)` and `emitAll(mRecordDao.listRecord().map { Result.Success(it) })` are not launched.

Comment: After I removed the wrapped code `expectedChangeTicker.flatMapLatest`,  the both `emit(Result.Loading)` and `emitAll(mRecordDao.listRecord().map { Result.Success(it) })` are launched, but they keep launch, never stop

Comment: There could be some issues. I didn't test it, and I don't know compose, so the compose part might not be wrong. It's normal for a Flow from Room to suspend forever when you collect it. `emit(Result.Loading)` is supposed to launch first every time--isn't that what you want?

Comment: After I removed the wrapped code `expectedChangeTicker.flatMapLatest,`  the `val listRecord: Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>=... ` can be launched only one time if I remove `either emit(Result.Loading)`  or `emitAll(mRecordDao.listRecord().map { Result.Success(it) })  `, I don't know why.

Comment: Do you  mean `expectedChangeTicker.emit(Unit)` in fun `addSomething` will cause `val listRecord` is refresh and launch  `emit(Result.Loading)` again?

Comment: Thanks! You have converted `val listRecord` as `MutableSharedFlow` in `class RecordRepository()`, `MutableSharedFlow` is hot flow, why do you need to convert `val listRecord` as hot flow using `shareIn` in `class SoundViewModel()` again ?

Comment: Even though `listRecord` collects from a hot flow, it is itself a cold flow. The `flow` builder creates a cold flow. Without converting it to a SharedFlow, every observer would see the initial loading state and have to restart collection of the DAO `listRecord()` flow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `produceState`. You can simply collect the flow returned by Dao in your composable using `collectAsState()` extension function.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column( ) {       
        val queryList by viewModel.listRecord.collectAsState(Result.Loading)

        when (queryList){
            is Result.Error  ->  { ...}
            is Result.Loading -> { ... }
            is Result.Success -> { ... }
        }

    }
}

class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(...): ViewModel() {

    val listRecord = aRecordRepository.listRecord()
}


class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val mRecordDao:RecordDao) {
    fun listRecord(): Flow<List<MRecord>> {
        return mRecordDao.listRecord()
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
If you want to emit the loading state from the flow itself, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
class RecordRepository @Inject constructor(private val mRecordDao: RecordDao) {
    fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {
        return flow {                       // Create a new flow
            emit(Result.Loading)            // Emit loading state right away
            mRecordDao.listRecord().collect {
                emit(Result.Success(it))    // Emit success state upon receiving data from dao
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The most important  things is how to emit Result.Loading when I query records.

Comment: I have edited the answer. See if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! When I run your code, I get the same result just like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731999/why-does-a-flow-which-return-records-from-room-keep-to-emit-data-when-i-add-onst

Comment: The app will keep to emit data when I use your code.